# shuffle CSV file data according to their labels

Tags: python, csv, shuffle

Suppose I have two CSV files, each of them has 100 rows. Each row in two CSV files has the same index and label, thus, these 100 rows can be viewed as the pair data set.

My purpose is to shuffle either of CSV files to make the data unpaired according to their different labels.

For example, input:

```
1st CSV            2nd CSV          label
data_1             data_1'           12
data_2             data_2'           6
 ...                ...              ...
```

Output:

```
data_1             data_2'    
 ...                 ...
```

Because data_1 and data_2' have different labels (12 and 6 respectively), thus, they are considered as unpaired data. My purpose is to select any number of data that has different labels with data_1.

Is there any python libraries or methods to make it?

Comment: It takes 3 steps: read the data using [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), shuffle the data using [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), write the data using [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: @zvone How to make sure the data is unpaired with different labels?

Comment: If you shuffle it, it will be unpaired. The chance of having a match on 100 rows after shuffling is 1 to 9.33e+157

Comment: @zvone I modified the question, any suggestion from you there?

Comment: So you want to ensure that none of the rows is a match? I don't think there is a built-in function for that. You should probably shuffle once and then shuffle again only rows with a match or something in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the csv content, using python's **random.shuffle()** function. Here is a sample/test code in python:

```
> cat ./shuffle_rows.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = ""
for i in range(5):
    data += "label_%d, data_%d, ...\n" % (i, i)

print("======== Input ========")
print data

import random
data = data.split("\n")
random.shuffle(data)  # shuffle modifies the sequence
data="\n".join(data)

print("======== Output ========")
print data

> ./shuffle_rows.py
======== Input ========
label_0, data_0, ...
label_1, data_1, ...
label_2, data_2, ...
label_3, data_3, ...
label_4, data_4, ...

======== Output ========
label_1, data_1, ...

label_4, data_4, ...
label_2, data_2, ...
label_3, data_3, ...
label_0, data_0, ...
```

Comment: I did not realize someone already answered this correctly, while I was answering this.

Comment: In shuffle, I don't need to care about the labels?

Comment: No, it just shuffles the rows (sequence indices). The row/content itself is un-modified.

Comment: So you shuffle one of cvs file with corresponding label, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you shuffle only one of the cvs file content- read, shuffle and write back.

However, I did not understand what you mean by corresponding label - can provide a sample input and sample intended output.

Comment: I modified my question, you can check it out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is suggesting to move this to a chat discussion - but I do not have enough permission/reputation to do that. So, I am replying by adding another answer, to your modified question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct Python method/api to do it. From what I understand, you want to shuffle the content such that there are no matches (pairing), when compared line to line. So, you need to implement this shuffling. Since, I spent quite some time on this and did not want to give up - here is my last go at this. Hope it helps you to modify it further, if needed.

```
> cat ./disjoint.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
NUM_ITEMS = 10

data = []
for i in range(NUM_ITEMS):
    #data.append("data_%d" % (i if i%2 == 0 else i/2))  # for negative testing: create some duplicates
    data.append("data_%d" % (i))

output = list(data) # copy

def display(d, o):
    print("%3s | %8s | %8s | %6s" % ("#", "Data", "Output", "Match?"))
    len1 = len(d)
    len2 = len(o)
    lenb = max(len1, len2)
    for i in range(lenb):
        i1 = d[i] if i < len1 else "None1"
        i2 = o[i] if i < len2 else "None2"
        print("%3d | %8s | %8s | %6s" % (i, i1, str(i2), "Err" if not i2 else "Yes" if (i1 == i2) else "No"))

print("==================== Input ==================")
display(data, output)

uniq = set(data) # list without duplicates.
for i in range(NUM_ITEMS):
    d = data[i]

    tmp_uniq = set(uniq) # copy
    if d in tmp_uniq:
        tmp_uniq.remove(d) # exclude current paired item.
    if len(tmp_uniq) == 0:
        output[i] = None
        continue

    tmp_uniq = list(tmp_uniq) # shuffle works only on list
    random.shuffle(tmp_uniq) # shuffle remaining non-matching items
    a_non_matching = tmp_uniq[0]
    output[i] = a_non_matching
    uniq.remove(a_non_matching)

print("==================== Output ==================")
display(data, output)
```

And, here is the output from this new test/sample code:

```
> ./disjoint.py
==================== Input ==================
  # |     Data |   Output | Match?
  0 |   data_0 |   data_0 |    Yes
  1 |   data_1 |   data_1 |    Yes
  2 |   data_2 |   data_2 |    Yes
  3 |   data_3 |   data_3 |    Yes
  4 |   data_4 |   data_4 |    Yes
  5 |   data_5 |   data_5 |    Yes
  6 |   data_6 |   data_6 |    Yes
  7 |   data_7 |   data_7 |    Yes
  8 |   data_8 |   data_8 |    Yes
  9 |   data_9 |   data_9 |    Yes
==================== Output ==================
  # |     Data |   Output | Match?
  0 |   data_0 |   data_5 |     No
  1 |   data_1 |   data_2 |     No
  2 |   data_2 |   data_0 |     No
  3 |   data_3 |   data_1 |     No
  4 |   data_4 |   data_6 |     No
  5 |   data_5 |   data_9 |     No
  6 |   data_6 |   data_7 |     No
  7 |   data_7 |   data_8 |     No
  8 |   data_8 |   data_4 |     No
  9 |   data_9 |   data_3 |     No
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time, I have been working on it using Pandas. I will try your method later

Comment: Definitely. I want to find a way to discuss that with you. Do you know how to use the discussion?